# Unable to prevent the onplay event after pause is fired inside the seeking event handler in React

Tags: reactjs, video, dom-events, html5-video, react-player

I am creating a functionality in Video Player using the **<video>** tag inside my React js project. I have a child component **VideoPlayer** which has the <video> element and a parent component *VideoPage* which is handled through a custom hook file **videos-hook.js**

Here is the code for the same - ***VideoPlayer.js***

```
import { forwardRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import { useStyles } from "./style";
import { ReactComponent as PlayIconSvg } from "../../../assets/images/play-icon.svg";

const VideoPlayer = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const {
    styles,
    url,
    thumbnailImage,
    width = "100%",
    height,
    isPlayIconVisible,
    onVideoPlay,
    onVideoPause,
    onVideoSeeking,
    onVideoTimeUpdate,
    onVideoEnded,
    onVideoPlayIconClick,
  } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref?.current?.load();
  }, [url]);

  const playIconVisibility = (isPlayIconVisible) => {
    let playIcon = null;
    if (isPlayIconVisible) {
      playIcon = (
        <PlayIconSvg
          id="activityVideoPlayIcon"
          className={classes.playBtn}
          onClick={() => onVideoPlayIconClick(ref)}
        />
      );
    }
    return playIcon;
  };
  return (
    <>
        <div className={classes.wrapper}>
          <video
            id="video"
            controls
            preload="none"
            disablePictureInPicture
            ref={ref}
            controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"
            width={width}
            height={height}
            poster={thumbnailImage}
            onPlay={(e) => onVideoPlay(e)}
            onPause={() => onVideoPause(ref)}
            onTimeUpdate={() => onVideoTimeUpdate(ref)}
            onSeeking={(e) => onVideoSeeking(e, ref)}
            onEnded={() => onVideoEnded(ref)}
          >
            <source src={url} />
          </video>

          {playIconVisibility(isPlayIconVisible)}
        </div>
    </>
  );
});

export default VideoPlayer;
```

**VideoPage.js (snippet)**

```
 const getVideoPlayer = () => {
    let videoPlayer = null;
    if (isPlayerVisible) {
      videoPlayer = (
        <Grid id="video-player-grid" className={classes.videoPlayerContainer}>
          <VideoPlayer
            id="video-player-container"
            videoTitle={videoTitle}
            videoUrl={videoUrl}
            isPlayIconVisible={isPlayIconVisible}
            onVideoPlay={handleVideoPlay}
            onVideoPlayIconClick={onVideoPlayIconClick}
            onVideoPause={onVideoPause}
            thumbnailImage={thumbnail}
            onVideoSeeking={onVideoSeeking}
            onVideoTimeUpdate={onVideoTimeUpdate}
            onVideoEnded={onVideoEnded}
          ></VideoPlayer>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
    return videoPlayer;
  };
```

**videos-hook.js (snippet)**

```
  const handleVideoPlay = (event) => {
    setPlayIconVisible(false);
  };
  const onVideoPause = () => {
    setPlayIconVisible(true);
  };
  const onVideoTimeUpdate = (playerRef) => {
    if (playerRef?.current && !playerRef?.current.seeking) {
      setSupposedCurrentTime(playerRef.current.currentTime);
    }
  };
  const onVideoSeeking = (e, playerRef) => {
    const delta = playerRef?.current.currentTime - supposedCurrentTime;
    if (delta > 0.01) {
      playerRef.current.currentTime = supposedCurrentTime;
      setShowVideoWarningModal(true);
      playerRef?.current?.pause();
    }
  };
  const onVideoEnded = async () => {
    setSupposedCurrentTime(0);
    if (videoItem?.activity?.activityCompleted === false) {
      const success = await handleVideoWatchedActivity();

}
```

I want that every time the user tries to seek forward the video, I do not allow him to seek forward and the video should pause as he needs to watch the entire video before earning points. He can seek backward. I am able to prevent him from seeking forward but not able to pause the video.

The issue is that my play event keeps on keeping fired after the seeking event is over. Also, I tried [this solution](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2444) but this hides the video player altogether.

The **forward arrow key →** perfectly captures the functionality I want as I think the play/pause event on **→** key does not trigger.